# Which group theory books could teach me how to determine the set of nonisomorphic groups of a given order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have read **sylow theorem** from **Contemporary abstract algebra** by **Joseph A Gallian**. At first I could not understand the theorems, although after searching internet and getting some good pdfs I understood these theorems properly using group action. Although that did not completely cleared my concept. As after trying to solve number of nonisomorphic groups of  given order I found out that I really could not solve it properly most of them. I once again searched internet but could not find any group articles that would clear up my concept. So it would be great if you can suggest me any books, article or anything that would clear up the doubts I have. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if you are more specific about your conceptual doubts so that we can tell which book might help you.

Comment: Number of non isomorphic groups of any given order. This is the main problem I have

Comment: [This search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbook-recommendation%5D%5Bgroup-theory%5D+basic) yields a bunch of good hits to answer your question, and I don't really understand why we need another "basic group theory book" post.  Maybe if you gave it a non-useless title the question would be better. Like "which textbooks cover the problem of finding nonisomorphic groups of the same order?"

Comment: Thank you for the edit. But I think one should not judge the post based on the title

Answer (score 0):

Beachy-Blair: Abstract Algebra is a really good book in introductory abstract. algebgra

Robert B Ash: Basic Abstract algebra is also really good book.

I would suggest these two.

Comment: Does it deal with the problem I have

Comment: Most definitely

Comment: Ok I will. Thanks

Comment: It looks really advanced and include many extra topics. Can u tell me a book more basic and has more elaborate section on group action and finding non isomorphic groups of a given order. Thanks

Comment: John S Rose: A course on group theory. What you seek is not elementary which means you will need to read through some advanced texts.